# Are LED drivers inter-switchable?

Tags: power-supply, led, driver, led-strip

MR16 type LED bulbs need their halogen counterparts' driver replaced due to low power consumption and they require an "LED driver" that can deliver the necessary wattage.

On the other hand, LED strips are usually sold as "kits" with single, heavy-duty PSUs.

**My question:**

- Are LED drivers which convert AC to 12v 10w, 20w, 30w, 50w etc. currents interswitchable? Can they be used to power parts of LED strips as well?
- Would it be necessary to use a circuit breaker?
- If yes, what amperage for the circuit breaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the specification of the bulbs concerned and also to be sure whether the output of the existing power supplies is AC or DC.

MR16 LED bulbs, as opposed to isolated high power LEDs, are often (even usually) sold as 12V rated bulbs. If the existing power supply is 12V DC as opposed to AC then the LED bulbs can often be substituted directly. Many MR16 and similar 12V LED bulbs have inbuilt diode bridges allowing operation form 12VAC supplies - see example driver at end.

Note that if the existing halogen drivers are based on iron transformer technology

- The output may indeed be AC.
- The transformer magnetisation current may be large compared to the LEd load and you may not get as high efficiency gains as you expected.

It is technically possible to operate a number of new LED circuits from a single supply if it is possible to disconnect the old drivers so there is direct connection from supply to LEDs via wiring.

A driver rated at W watts will supply about W/12 amps at 12v.
An A Amp supply will provide about 12 x A Watts at 12 Volts.

You can almost always buy 12V LED bulbs without drivers. Where 'bare' LED s are driven and the LED current is controlled by the power supply (= driver) rather than by the drive voltage, it is more likely that bulb and driver will be sold together.

Be careful about dimming - some LED bulbs will work with existing phase controlled dimmers but many will not.

Note that almost all LED bulbs have power inputs below or well below claimed ratings.

Lifetimes of no-name or strange brand LED bulbs may be short or very or very very short. Generally cheap means low grade in some way.  But high cost MAY NOT mean high quality. Name brand bulbs are the best protection and even then be careful. Also, watch for "clones" of name brands.

[Chinese listing of 12V LED bulbs for various fitting types](http://www.dhgate.com/wholesale/mr16/s117004002.html?f=bm|019015005005%20Led%20Bulbs%20MR16%20KC%20PS%20AW|46465372152|paid_search|adwords|led%20mr16%20light%20bulbs|019015005005%20Led%20Bulbs%20KC%20PS%20AW|YQX|c|b|019015005005|&gclid=CjwKEAjwp7WgBRCRxMCLx8mMnDMSJADncxS2esAYxjWY3BoGxh1spaCQ5h1SQYRRfbyOrPkbBT8HfBoCZQvw_wcB)

[24 language !!! LED bulb site](http://www.lightinthebox.com/c/led-light-bulbs_4657/All-3?currency=USD&litb_from=paid_adwords_search&adword_mt=b&adword_ct=34038094471&adword_kw=led%2012v%20mr16%20bulbs&adword_pos=1t2&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&gclid=CjwKEAjwp7WgBRCRxMCLx8mMnDMSJADncxS2HV2flXG-VhKkCDRS2s1T3w390TZ67qpSZQxQKjVv9RoC2PDw_wcB) - US face, Chinese source.

[ebay "best selling" MR16 page](http://www.ebay.com/gds/best-selling/mr16-led/v.html)

I do like these :-) [10 x MR16 drivers for $US12.50](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pc-MR16-DC12-24V-4-7x1W-Power-Supply-LED-Driver-for-4-7PCS-high-power-led-chip-/321334827335)

- Note 4 x Ss24 input diodes in bridge -  AC operation
- Buck converter to drive LEDs - IC hidden under 470 uF cap.
- Single diode at top left is output diode from high frequency converter.

[image]

Comment: Amazing and thorough answer. Thanks! Couldn't ask for more.